# Pumping lemma problem

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

I need some help with the following question:

One of the languages

$$L_1 = \{a^pb^{q+r}c^sd^{q+t}e^{p+r} \mid p, q, r, s \ge 0\ , s > t\}$$
$$L_2 = \{a^{p+q}b^rc^sd^{q+r}e^s \mid p, q, r, s \ge 0\}$$

is context-free and the other is not. Build a context-free grammar for the one that is. For the other one provide a proof that it is not regular, or that it is not context-free.

How do I approach this problem ? I think that L2 is context-free because no comparisions are made. L1 is not context-free.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually wrong. I'll give you a hint for the grammar of $L_1$. Rewrite it as $a^p b^r b^q c^{s-t} c^t d^t d^q e^r e^p$. Although I have no idea how the case $s = 0, q = 0$ (thus $q+t < 0$) is supposed to work.

For $L_2$ there is an implicit comparison $r \leq q+r$. Take $p = q = 0$ so that the string is $b^rc^sd^re^s$. You should be able to apply the lemma here easily.